# Let {$x_n$} and {$y_n$} be bounded sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let {$x_n$} and {$y_n$} be bounded sequences. I want to show that
{$x_n + y_n$} is a bounded sequence.

I tried to use definition of limits, but I don't think I can say that {$x_n$} and {$y_n$} converges to x, and y because even if sequences are bounded, they can still be divergent.

What should I do?

Comment: $|x_n|\leq M$ and $|y_n|\leq N$ for some $M,N>0$ and every $n\in\Bbb N$. What about $|x_n+y_n|\leq ???$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Triangle inequality.

Suppose 
$$
|x_n|<M_1\\
|y_n|<M_2
$$
for any $n$.

Then 
$$
|x_n|+|y_n|<M_1+M_2\implies |x_n+y_n|\leq |x_n|+|y_n|<M_1+M_2
$$
for any $n$ and we conclude.

Comment: Omg.... It can be like this easy. Thank you.

Comment: @user421044 sure thing. When in doubt, use the triangle inequality